# How to access toolchain info in bazel aspect

Tags: bazel

I'm looking for a way to access toolchain information in an custom aspect. Ideally would be to access the cc_toolchain rule in the aspect, but somehow the aspects are not run for this kind of rule. Any ideas how to get information about the used toolchain? Include paths, compiler flags, etc. ?

Comment: Answering myself:
Based on https://github.com/bazelbuild/intellij/blob/master/aspect/intellij_info_impl.bzl

attr_aspects should contain '_cc_toolchain'

Comment: You can place the comment as an answer in the bottom text area field

Answer (score 0):

Based on github.com/bazelbuild/intellij/blob/master/aspect/… attr_aspects should contain '_cc_toolchain'